# self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex and perform function in another view controller

Tags: swift

I have 4 view controllers in tab bar controller and each embedded with navigation controller. The problem is, I have researched and find the best way to navigate from Viewcontroller0 to Viewcontroller 1 in tab Bar is to use `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`, and it works properly. However, I wish to do the function immediately after the navigation. The following is my attempt but did not work. Anyone have the idea? Big Thanks.

```
  @IBAction func GOGOBut(_ sender: Any) {

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

    if let VC = presentingViewController as? TutorViewController {
        VC.observeBBCases()
    }
    //NotificationCenter.default.post(name:  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadBAFS"), object: nil)

}
```

observeBBCases() is the function in TutorViewController
And self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 is to go the TutorViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `UINavigationController` which contains `TutorViewController` using the index `1`. And get the root view controller `TutorViewController` of the navigation controller. Then you can call the method `observeBBCases`

```
@IBAction func GOGOBut(_ sender: Any) {
    if let navigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController,
        let vc = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? TutorViewController {
            vc.observeBBCases()
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
}
```